# how to populate data from textarea to jlist

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtextarea, jlist

I'm having a problem with the jlist..the data is showing in my jlist whenever i put a data on my textarea but instead of populating the data it will remove the previous one and will only show the current input.. here is my code by the way

```
private void postButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String theAccountID = showAccountID.getText();
    String theFirstName = showFName.getText();
    String theLastName = showSName.getText();
    String name = theFirstName + " " + theLastName;

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateAndTimeCreated = dateFormat.format(date);

    String show = thePost.getText();
    Post obj = new Post(show);
    String post = obj.getContent();

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    String postOutput = dateAndTimeCreated + "      " + name + ": " + post;
    try 
    {
        if(obj.getContent().equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This status update appears to be blank. Please write something to update your status.");
        }

        else
        {
            model.addElement(postOutput);
            showPostStatus.setModel(model);

            String sql = "insert into Post(account_id,post,datePostCreated) values (?,?,?)";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,theAccountID);
            pst.setString(2,post);
            pst.setString(3,dateAndTimeCreated);
            pst.execute();
            pst.close();
        }  
    } 

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

    thePost.setText(null);

}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-creating the `ListModel` each time `postButtonActionPerformed` is called, this (effectively) discards everything else that the `JList` was displaying in favor of the contents of the new model

You could consider create a `DefaultListModel` as an instance field, set it as the `JList`s model and simply update this model as required

You could also do something like...

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)showPostStatus.getModel();
// update the model...
```

You won't need to apply the model, as any changes you make will be reflected within the `JList` itself automatically...

Comment: THANKS SIR! I tried putting DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel(); outside the postButton and it work! So that's why it is not populating because it is recreating, but the code that you provide DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)showPostStatus; has an error.